# Android Test running failed : No Test results

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin

Hi i am trying to run the example instrumented test class in my project but everytime i run it i get this error:

```
Test running failed: no test results
Empty test suit
```

Here is my example intrumented test class

```
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * See [testing documentation](http://d.android.com/tools/testing).
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        val appContext = androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
        assertEquals("com.app", appContext.packageName)
    }
}
```

Here is my gradle build filefor tests:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    testOptions {
        execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }
}

dependencies {

    def mockito = "2.18.3"
//android instrumental test
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.jraska.livedata:testing-ktx:0.6.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.jraska.livedata:testing:0.6.0'

    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockito"

    androidTestImplementation 'org.koin:koin-test:1.0.2'

    //unit test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockito"
    testImplementation 'org.koin:koin-test:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'com.jraska.livedata:testing-ktx:0.6.0'
    testImplementation 'com.jraska.livedata:testing:0.6.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0'
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you run it? Just right-clicking on the test in Studio and clicking Run... should run the test

Comment: Yes i run it like that. What I've noticed is that I had the mockito inline function in my androidTest resource folder and when I got rid of that I get a different error saying something along the lines of mockito is os dependent error which the mockito inline function supposed to fix

Comment: Any suggestions? Still get the same error

Comment: This is a bug with kotlin tests in recent Android Studio versions. Make sure you've updated Android Studio to the latest version, which is currently 3.2.1

Comment: is there a big track log for this? This also doesnt work of i manually do gradlew connectedAndroidTest

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Updating my Android Studio to version 3.3 AND removing

```
testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
}
```

worked

Comment: Amazeballs - this was key!
Why doesn't Google add this as a note in there own setup since this was something that was needed earlier...

Comment: It's Google that's why. Poor documentation

Comment: This is ridiculous. Removing this gradle option was necessary without any readable error message.

Comment: Would someone be able to provide an explanation why this works? Just out of curiosity

Comment: but... this is not an answer! If i need to setup my tests that way, that every test will run app at fresh install state - i need ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR

Comment: in my case update androidx.test:orchestrator from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 helped

Comment: If you are using androidx jetpack then follow instructions from @Robert Liberatore. Removing it is a workaround to get individual tests to run but for the rest of us that need to run a lot of tests and dont want to run them individually we need the test orchestrator.

Answer (score 12):

You're entirely set up using AndroidX for testing, except for the test orchestrator.  Instead of removing the test orchestrator (which is very useful), change

`execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'`

to

`execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'`

Comment: @Chisko There are lots of different ways that this error can come up.  My answer is specific to OP's gradle file. I suggest consulting official docs to make sure you have everything set up correctly: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project

Comment: Dude, you think I haven't been through their docs? My error was exactly the same as OP's and you solution didn't work, I had to remove the line even if I didn't want to, and now espresso works.

Comment: @Chisko Your error being the same does not mean they have the same cause. I would suggest if this not working for you matters, then post your own question with your build file.

Comment: @Robert Liberatore this was my issue. I didn't even notice i wasn't using ANDROIDX. Thanks!

Comment: Removing it altogether fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because android studio could not install the apk because of conflicting content provider's authorities. Uninstalling the apk worked